# Scrapy NotImplementedError

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to fetch some links before scraping data from the individual pages but am getting the `NotImplementedError` - traceback below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 588, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/spiders/__init__.py", line 76, in parse
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError
2017-10-13 06:03:58 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2017-10-13 06:03:58 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 273,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 81464,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 13, 5, 3, 58, 550062),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 2,
 'log_count/ERROR': 1,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'spider_exceptions/NotImplementedError': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 13, 5, 3, 56, 552516)}
2017-10-13 06:03:58 [scrapy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

I have tried:

Adding `DOWNLOAD_HANDLERS = {'s3': None,}` to `settings.py`

Which didn't seem to do anything, I then switched to from `crapy.Spider` to `scrapy.spiders.CrawlSpider` which did not throw the error messages, however, it also does not print out my `final_url` - am I correct in thinking that it should if this is set up correctly? My code below:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.http import Request
import scrapy


class Test_spider(scrapy.spiders.CrawlSpider):
    name = "Spider_Testing"
    allowed_domains = ["http://www.example.com/"]
    start_urls = (
                       "http://www.example.com/followthrough",
    )

    def parse_links(self, response): 
            links = response.xpath('//form/table/tr/td/table//a[div]/@href').extract() 
            for link in links:
                base_url = "http://www.example.com/followthrough" # the full addresss after/ is slightly different than start urls but that should not matter?
                final_url = response.urljoin(base_url, links)
                print(final_url) #test 1
                print(Request(final_url, callback=self.parse_final)) #test 2
                yield Request(final_url, callback=self.parse_final)

    def parse_final(self, response):
        pass
```

So my questions for this one are:

- Is this the correct logic?
- Is my test print for the `final_url` correct? - I am thinking #1 is not #2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes from missing `parse` method. Since you don't implement the `start_requests`, its default behavior is:

> The default implementation generates `Request(url, dont_filter=True)`
>   for each url in start_urls.

It doesn't set the callback parameter, so it will try to call `parse` as default:

> If a Request doesn’t specify a callback, the spider’s parse() method
>   will be used. Note that if exceptions are raised during processing,
>   errback is called instead.

You can fix it by implementing [starts_requests](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.start_requests) and specify the callback parameter:

```
def start_requests:
    yield Request(start_url, callback=parse_links)
```

**Update:**
`response.urljoin(url)` recieves only one argument:

> Constructs an absolute url by combining the Response’s url with a
>   possible relative url.

You should use `response.urljoin(link)` or `urlparse.urljoin(base_url, link)`. And also make sure that the links here are relative urls.

**Update2:**
You can add following code and run it:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
    process = CrawlerProcess({
        'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)'
    })

    process.crawl(Test_spider)
    process.start()
```

It allows you to run scrapy from a script, so you can use `ipdb` or debug tools in IDE to step into it.

Comment: Thank you @CtheSky - that resolved the error message but unfortunately I'm getting `Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)`  - I assume that is why `print(Request(final_url, callback=parse_links))` is not working?

Comment: I think `links` might be empty, can you check the xpath expression?

Comment: When I use `response.xpath('//form/table/tr/td/table//a[div]/@href').extract()` in the shell it returns the results I want e.g. `u'lphs.asp?id=279&city=london'` which when (manually) appended to my base url goes to the page I want. I tried just running that just that in my spider and it returned nothing again, so I'm a little stumped!

Comment: I think it could be related to `urljoin`, see the update. And I think there should be an error message somewhere.

Comment: Ahh thanks for that! I tried both, frustratingly, neither seemed to do the trick :s

Comment: I think you may debug into it (see the update), there must be a reason. BTW, do you have the method `parse_room`?

Comment: Thanks for that one, `parse_room` is actually `parse_final` in my code. Do you think we should take this to chat to avoid clogging up the page? https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156873/room-for-maverick-and-cthesky

Comment: I've put all the things I could come up with based on the given info. Maybe if you have new error message or clue you can update the question so more people can see it and help you.

Comment: Okay, just had a few qs about update 2. But I'm sure I'll figure it out! Thanks for your suggestions :)